# Why are Reflection's GetProperty() or GetField() not instance or extension methods?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm fairly new to Reflection in C#, and I think I understand how to use it to solve some problems.

However, what I find confusing is the syntax for methods like GetProperty() or GetField().

To get an instance field, you have to do `typeof(MyClass).GetField("fieldName").GetValue(myClassInstance)`. Which is not the most straightforward thing.

Wouldn't it make more sense to get instance fields or properties by using something like an extension method? Something like:

```
myClassInstance.GetField("fieldName").Value
```

And use the previous example for things like static fields/properties/methods.

It just feels more natural than the first example, where you must pass your class instance.

Again, I am new to Reflection, so there might be some disadvantages I'm overlooking.

Comment: Field metadata is a property of the class, not the instance. With your syntax, you need an instance in order to get information about the field.

Comment: Another reason is that extension methods weren't always part of c# so when the reflection code was first written they clearly couldn't have used extension methods...

Comment: @Blorgbeard Is there an advantage in accessing the field metadata from the class, apart from static properties/fields/etc? I feel like the regular syntax would be better just for those.

Comment: Of course - why create an instance if you don't need to? The only time when you need an instance is when you want to read/write a field value. Every other time, you don't.

Comment: E.g. Maybe you're scanning for classes that match some criteria - maybe they have a field with a certain name and type. You don't want to have to `Activator.CreateInstance` each one just to check if it matches your pattern.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I completely agree with you there. You shouldn't have to create instances to read field names or types. But, given that many times you need the field value (from a class instance) at runtime, why do I have to use a `Type` method, and not an instance method? I'm looking for information about the instance. It just doesn't feel natural to me. Now, of course the `typeof(...).GetField(...)` makes more sense for the scenario you described.

Comment: Well, how often are you using reflection to read fields? It's not normally a very common pattern. Yes, there could be an extension method on Object to `GetFieldValue(string name)`, and you could write one yourself. The only reason anyone can give you that it doesn't exist in the framework is that the designers didn't think it was a valuable (enough) feature.

Comment: And personally, I prefer to keep reflection methods separate from the standard object model. Reflection breaks the normal rules around access modifiers etc. If reflection was a standard part of every object's public API, what would be the point in making anything `private`?

Comment: Actually the reflection entry point is there on every instance `obj.GetType().Get...`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I didn't know that reflection bypasses access Modifiers! More on topic, you're right that making an extension method would just make stuff cluttered and wouldn't really give any advantage, given that, as you say, its not a really common pattern. Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To get an instance field, you have to do `typeof(MyClass).GetField("fieldName").GetValue(myClassInstance)`. Which is not the most straightforward thing.

Well, not quite. To get an instance field you have to do `fieldInfo.GetValue(myClassInstance)`.

Sure, starting with the compile-time (indeed, coding-time) knowledge that `myClassInstance` is a `MyClass` would mean that the way you get that `fieldInfo` is through `typeof(MyClass).GetField("fieldName")` but then one would just do `myClassInstance.fieldName` or if a cast was necessary `((MyClass)myClassInstance).fieldName` which is easier, faster and less error-prone.

Reflection is useful when we can't just do `myClassInstance.fieldName` because we only obtained the `Type` and/or the `FieldInfo` at runtime. What we need then is the flexibility to let us handle a wide variety of cases of just what we do or don't know at compile-time.

Now, it's perfectly possible to create types and methods (instance or extension) such that `myClassInstance.GetField("fieldName").Value` would work. But how useful would that be?

First, as stated above, it's pointless if we know the type of `myClassInstance` at compile-time. But also, what type should this `GetField()` method work on? The compile-time type is clearly pointless, but should it be the run-time type (the type one would find by calling `GetType()`)? That would probably be the most commonly useful type, but we might want to force the lookup to be on a particular base type (or interface type — clearly not in the case of looking up fields, but perhaps for methods, properties and events), so we've lost flexibility in this and gained only for a particular subset of cases currently catered for.

So while adding this functionality would be useful in some cases, the current API would remain necessary in some other cases. It could only be an *also* convenience API, not the primary one.

And in fact we have that convenience API, for it is what `dynamic` gives us.

```
((dynamic)myClassInstance).fieldName
```

This allows us to get or set the field called `fieldName` on the runtime-type of `myClassInstance` and generally is even more convenient than the API you propose. It also has the advantage that the separate compile-time type (at runtime `dynamic` is the same as `object` at compile-time the compiler treats it differently at compile-time by using late rather than early binding). So we don't have a public surface on `object` full of methods for a pretty rare case (and indeed a case that **should** be rare; the speed, typing of return types and above all guards against incorrectness that come from type safety are to be favoured whenever possible) and also get `dynamic` as the return type too which is good because we're more likely to want to do more of this sort of late-binding when it's how we obtained an instance the first time.

Comment: That's a fantastic answer. To be honest, I have hardly ever used `dynamic`. Now I see it's such a powerful tool but obviously, should only be used only when it's strictly required since it's very sensitive to typos. Thanks for the long explanation!

Comment: Typos aren't the worse, since they tend to be caught the first time you test. It's more complicated cases where you find yourself trying to use a method via `dynamic` on an object that doesn't support that method, but then can't see right away why you had passed such an object to the method that used `dynamic` because the decision was several steps back in the call chain that will really hurt. There are also some things it just can't handle (anything that can't be boxed). Really, it gives one all of the advantages of a late-bound language, but at the cost of the disadvantages of one.